# Spark Master Re-Submits endlessly after IOException on the Worker Node Application/Job Submitted

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am quite new to Spark world.
In our application we have an in-built Spark standalone cluster(**Version 2.4.3**) which takes in submitted jobs by our main data engine loader application via spark submit master URL.

We have 3 worker slave nodes on different VMs. Interestingly because of some IOException which I am posting in a very limited and cryptic format to limit system internals. The Master assumes it needs to **Re-Submit** the same job/application to the **same worker** over and over again(10s of thousands of time)

Worker App/Job Logs which is the same for every Job RE-Submission

```
2020-04-28 11:31:15,466 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication enabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(app_prod); groups with view permissions: Set(); users with modify permissions: Set(app_prod); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1748)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$1(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:201)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to load.box.ancestor.com/xx.xxx.xx.xxx:30xxx
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: load.box.ancestor.com/xx.xxx.xx.xxx:30xxx
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
```

Below the Master Logs which is RE-SUBMITTING the same job over and over even though by the look of it the worker job/app is giving EXIT(1) signal

Spark Master job Logs:

```
2020-04-28 11:30:49,750 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-27789323082123-23782/11635 on worker worker-29990224233349-yy.yy.yyy.yyy-7078
2020-04-28 11:30:52,195 INFO master.Master: Removing executor app-27789323082123-23782/11635 because it is EXITED
2020-04-28 11:30:52,195 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-27789323082123-23782/11636 on worker worker-29990224233349-yy.yy.yyy.yyy-7078
2020-04-28 11:30:54,651 INFO master.Master: Removing executor app-27789323082123-23782/11636 because it is EXITED
2020-04-28 11:30:54,651 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-27789323082123-23782/11637 on worker worker-29990224233349-yy.yy.yyy.yyy-7078
2020-04-28 11:30:57,201 INFO master.Master: Removing executor app-27789323082123-23782/11637 because it is EXITED
2020-04-28 11:30:57,201 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-27789323082123-23782/11638 on worker worker-29990224233349-yy.yy.yyy.yyy-7078
2020-04-28 11:30:59,769 INFO master.Master: Removing executor app-27789323082123-23782/11638 because it is EXITED
2020-04-28 11:30:59,769 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-27789323082123-23782/11639 on worker worker-29990224233349-yy.yy.yyy.yyy-7078
```

My Query is : We haven't modified spark.deploy.maxExecutorRetries
so it should be default 10.

Does this error or repetitive submission impacted by this parameter or we need to check out another config for this issue in case Spark master is not able to recognize that the Worker job failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We noticed that `spark.port.maxRetries` was set to x which along with `spark.driver.port` and `spark.driver.blockManager.port` per job was assigning only x/2 spark.driver.port for each job. For the next queued job this parameter was restricting any more jobs and also keeps on re-submitting the job with the same port. The only option we could come up with was to `spark.port.maxRetries` to a more sizeable number.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting below config

```
spark.task.maxFailures = 2
```

Comment: I am not sure about this parameter. ```spark.task.maxFailures```4```Number of failures of any particular task before giving up on the job. The total number of failures spread across different tasks will not cause the job to fail; a particular task has to fail this number of attempts. Should be greater than or equal to 1. No of allowed retries = this value - 1.``` as per documentation; while more reading suggests that task is basically Spark's own staging tasks. Also, one relevant SO accepted answer  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593923/spark-task-maxfailures-not-working-as-expected]

Comment: Also, this issue can be resolved by fixing the Firewall issue between the ```load.box.ancestor.com/xx.xxx.xx.xxx:30xxx``` and Spark Worker node/port. But if this same issue recurs for some other runtime anomalies/exceptions there should be a limit for Re-Submission of these jobs by signalling client/master on Error/Exception.